# Turan-k graph definition help?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $n=qk+r$, where $r \in \left\{0,1,..,k-1\right\}$. The $Turan-k$ graph $T_k(n)$ on $n$ vertices is the completer $k$-partite graph with $k-r$ parts of size $q$ and $r$ parts of size $q+1$.

So I've been reading this definition over and over and yet I can't seem to grasp the part where there is "$k-r$ parts of size $q$ and $r$ parts of size $q+1$". What does this mean?

Also, for an example, considering $T_3(8)$ on 8 vertices, I know that
$8 = 2\cdot 3 + 2$, where in this case $q=2,k=3,r=2$ One quick question is that, is $r$ always $k-1$? or is it possible for it be less than $k-1$ but satisfies $n=qk+r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is simply that we want to have $k$ parts which are as equal as possible. If $n = qk + r$, then after we distribute $q$ vertices to each of the parts, there are $r$ vertices left, so $r$ parts will have size $k+1$ instead of size $q$.

It's possible for $r$ to have any value between $0$ and $k-1$. For example:

- For $\phantom{9}T_3(99)$, we have $\phantom{9}99 = 33\cdot 3 + 0$, so $q = 33$ and $r=0$. We get parts of sizes $33, 33, 33$.
- For $T_3(100)$, we have $100 = 33\cdot 3 + 1$, so $q=33$ and $r=1$. We get parts of sizes $33, 33, 34$.
- For $T_3(101)$, we have $101 = 33\cdot 3 + 2$, so $q=33$ and $r=2$. We get parts of sizes $33, 34, 34$.
- For $T_3(102)$, we have $102 = 34\cdot 3 + 0$, so $q=34$ and $r=0$. We get parts of sizes $34, 34, 34$.

Another way to express this division is that the $k$ parts have sizes $$\left\{ \left\lfloor \frac nk \right\rfloor, \left\lfloor \frac {n+1}k \right\rfloor, \left\lfloor \frac {n+2}k \right\rfloor, \dots, \left\lfloor \frac {n+k-1}k \right\rfloor\right\}$$ where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. This expression looks pretty, but it's not immediately obvious that the $k$ sizes add up to $n$.

(They do, and you can prove this by induction on $n$. For $n=0$, all these fractions round down to $0$. Going from $n$ to $n+1$ replaces $\left\lfloor \frac nk \right\rfloor$ by $\left\lfloor \frac {n+k}k \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor \frac nk \right\rfloor + 1$, so the total increases by $1$.)

Comment: what a wonderful explanation! thank you!